# Why does OpenCV recognize the object only in training images?

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, opencv3.0, lbph-algorithm

In order to make my iOS app recognize 1€, 2€ and 0.50€ coins I have been trying to use `opencv_createsamples` and `opencv_traincascade` to create my own classifier.xml. So, I cropped 60 images of 2€ coins from a short video like the following:

[image]

Then, I combined them with random backgrounds using `opencv_createsamples`. I obtained 12000 images similar to this:

[image]

and I ran the following commands:

`opencv_createsamples -img positives/i.jpg -bg negatives.txt -info i.txt -num 210 -maxidev 100 -maxxangle 0.0 -maxyangle 0.0 -maxzangle 0.9 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -w 48 -h 48` (for i from 0 to 60)

`cat *.txt > positives.txt`

`opencv_createsamples -info positives.txt -bg negatives.txt -vec 2.vec -num 12600 -w 48 -h 48`

`opencv_traincascade -data final -vec 2.vec -bg negatives.txt -numPos 12000 -numNeg 3000 -numStages 20 -featureType LBP -precalcValBufSize 2048 -precalcIdxBufSize 2048 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 48 -h 48`

Training stopped at 13-th stage. Once I got a `cascade.xml` I tried it at once (with `detectMultiScale()`) on a simple image taken by my smartphone but nothing is detected:

[image]

while if I give as input one of the images used as traning, then it works very good:

[image]

I can't really understand why this is happening and it's driving me insane, most of all because I have been trying to make it work for  weeks...would you please tell me where I am making the mistake?

The short program I wrote is here:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**) {

Mat src = imread("2b.jpg");

Mat src_gray;

std::vector<cv::Rect> money;

CascadeClassifier euro2_cascade;

cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
equalizeHist(src_gray, src_gray);

if ( !euro2_cascade.load( "cascade.xml" ) ) {
    printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
    return -1;
}

euro2_cascade.detectMultiScale( src_gray, money, 1.1, 3, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE/*CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE*/, cv::Size(10, 10),cv::Size(2000, 2000) );
printf("%d\n", int(money.size()));

for( size_t i = 0; i < money.size(); i++ ) {
    cv::Point center( money[i].x + money[i].width*0.5, money[i].y + money[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( src, center, cv::Size( money[i].width*0.5, money[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
}

namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imwrite("result.jpg",src);
}
```

I have also tried to take into consideration [feature homography](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) for my OpenCV version 3.1. Thus, I downloaded opencv_contrib for my version and tried to compile xfeatures2d module but I get a CMake error in CMakeList file...moreover xfeature2d is not even present inside opencv framework for xcode so even if I made it work on my pc then I could not use it in iOS anyway...

**UPDATE**

As advised, I've just tried to remove `equalizeHist(src_gray, src_gray);` and I have set the number of neighbors in detectMultiScale()`` and this is what I get:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

As someone suggested, following [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/15723/unable-to-create-positive-samples/) tutorial I have just created a .vec file using only the cropped positive images, the ones with only the coin. I used this command:

`opencv_createsamples -vec i.vec -w 48 -h 48 -num 210 -img ./positives/i.jpg -maxidev 100 -maxxangle 0 -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 0.9 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0`
(for i from 0 to 60)

So as you can see, there's no used background image to create samples. 
Then, after downloading [mergevec.py](https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec/blob/master/mergevec.py), I combined all the vectors file together. Now I'm gonna launch another LBP training...I hope it'll work better

Comment: Did you rotated your image when created training samples ?

Comment: as you can read from my question I gave -maxzangle 0.9 to opencv_createsamples. Is it wrong? What value should I give to get a 360' rotation?... Anyway I don't know if that is the problem because I also tried with a straight image and the result was the same. Unless it is imread() which rotates images...

Comment: When you put coin in the same pose as on image does it detect ?

Comment: No... I also tried to take a photo of the coin in the same pose but nothing happens. Which values should I give to opencv_createsamples to get a complete rotation? Is the mistake there?

Comment: Seems this will be usefull: http://athenanichol.com/blog/?p=815

Comment: @AndreySmorodov I had read that article but I still don't understand which rotation I'm supposed to give. Or better, if angles need to be in radiants and I want to consider a complete rotation, shall I give -maxzangle 6.28? I had tried it but I get an error...

Comment: I think it would be better to write an own tool and generate data set with it. Set random rotation scaling color noise, ...

Comment: Ehm...yes it could be a good idea but I'm very new to OpenCv and I don't know where to start from to write my own tool...

Comment: By the way, did you tried not equalize image, because I think you used not equalized images in training stage.

Comment: And may be it will be better to start from following something working like this: https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lego-detection-using-opencv/

Comment: @AndreySmorodov thank you for all your comments but I don't know what you're talking about concerning "By the way, did you tried not equalize image, because I think you used not equalized images in training stage"...? forgive me, I know I'm an ignorant but I'm really new to opencv...

Comment: I mean try not to do this: equalizeHist(src_gray, src_gray); in your code above.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov I have just tried to do what you said and I've also tried to rotate the image of 90° 4 times. I've just updated my question with the strange result I get...

Comment: Try reduce image size 4-5 times, your image is very large.

Comment: Just tried to reduce of 10% step by spep but it still does not work...

Comment: i'm not aware of what "detectMultiScale" does, but usually a statistical model that performs good on the training data and poorly on the test data suffers from overfitting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), which basically means that your model is too precise and tends to memorize the exact training samples thus failing to generalize. It can be solved with regularization techniques (the exact technique depends on the model you use)

Answer (score 1):

Your cascade was not trained properly. 
You should not only add different background, but also different scales and different rotations in 3 angles for your coin.
Also add more nagatives for training (you have many small detections that mean, that cascade is not trained on negatives)

Answer (score 1):

This could be the reason due to lack of training data that represent the total scenario of the possible cases. You are not representing full information to the Model. If you don't have more data,

1. You should rotate images, Crop them at random size and angle, Flipping (Mirroring along vertical edge) basically **Data Augmentation**
2. You can do **background separation** and then use the model for classification
3. Convert images to `grey scale` and then operate the classification model (sometime color might mislead the model)

Comment: If this solves the issue, Please add this as accepted Answer.